# Why do I get "500 can't connect to theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca :: 80 (bad hostname)" when I try to install modules?

Tags: perl, module, installation

Whenever I try to install a Perl module, I get the following error:

```
500 can't connect to theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca :: 80 (bad hostname)
```

I get the same error with both ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably have a proxy server. You may need to look at proxy configuration in whatever you're using to install modules.

Comment: @Sobrique, Nah, it doesn't resolve anymore.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, done. hah! I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `cpan`?

1. Start `cpan`.
2. Enter `o conf init urllist`.
3. Yes, you would you like `cpan` to automatically choose some CPAN mirror sites for you.
4. Enter `o conf commit`.
5. `exit`

Comment: How I can fix the proxy server. I am very new to it can you please explain me

Comment: I tried with CPAN as you told me ... but still the problem is not resolved unfortunately

Comment: Can you please suggest something else  please

Comment: ppm install Lingua::Stem error ::failed 500 acnt connect to theoryx5.winnipeg.ca :80 badhostname

Comment: @Zoya Khalid, 1) I've already explained that it's not a proxy problem, but that the repository no longer exists. 2) You're using `ppm`, not `cpan`, so my answer won't help you. I'm not deleteing it since it could still be of use to others. 3) Since you're using `ppm`, you'll need to update its configuration.